# Laravel generate routes based on defined url in env file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I use the following method to generate route URLs:

```
route('example')
```

It seems this method generated URLs based on the current URL `($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])` with binding to the defined routes in `api.php` file.
How can I use `APP_URL` defined in `env` file to generate the URLs instead of the current URL?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here ? route() will use the domain of the request as expected, it does not make sense to use APP_URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to you can force the domain :

```
URL::forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));
```

but that's not a good idea, you should always use the domain that the user used to access your app, you will have issues when changing the domain like that, like sessions issues

Answer (score 0):

I think u search for `asset()` or `url()`

`$url = asset('img/photo.jpg'); // return: http://example.com/assets/img/photo.jpg`

here the help
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#urls

Comment: asset or url will use domain from the request also, not APP_URL

Comment: ah ok :)
I am fine with the most helpers that are given in laravel
maybe @alex-greenwood has to configure a helper on it self ...
`config('admin.url')`